# How to fix flutter iOS crash with firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, dart, cocoapods

Before I tried to build my flutter app on Xcode for ios it was working perfectly. But then something strange happened and since I am getting error after error, and now I can't even install my app on the simulator anymore. I have cleaned and also completely deleted the ios file and rebuilt it, but I get each time different errors.

I think that there is a problem with the las Flutter update and Firebase.

This is my pubspec.yaml

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.10.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.12.2
  keyboard_avoider: ^0.1.2
  pin_code_fields: ^6.0.1
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.11.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
  youtube_player_flutter: ^7.0.0+7
  cached_network_image: ^2.5.0
  floor: ^0.18.0
  flutter_bloc: ^6.1.1
  equatable: ^1.2.5
  numberpicker: ^1.3.0
  charts_flutter: ^0.9.0
  flutter_time_picker_spinner: ^1.0.6+1
  vibration: ^1.7.3
  change_app_package_name: ^0.1.2
  random_string: ^2.1.0
  
  path_provider: ^1.6.27
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.9
  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.20.0+1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0
  firebase_storage: ^7.0.0
```

and this is the error output

```
Warning: You are using these overridden dependencies:                   
! sqflite 1.3.2+1 from git https://github.com/TinyProgrammers/sqflite.git at d345da in sqflite
Running "flutter pub get" in schwungfit...                       1.427ms
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                             18,0s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           92,8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[56843]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both ?? (0x1f09f8188) and ??
    (0x11b5ac2b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[56843]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both ?? (0x1f09f81d8) and ?? (0x11b5ac308).
    One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabaseQueue.m:9:
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabaseQueue.h:21
    8:99: note: parameter of overridden method is annotated with __attribute__((noescape))
    - (void)inDeferredTransaction:(__attribute__((noescape)) void (^)(FMDatabase *db, BOOL
    *rollback))block;
                                                                                                 ^
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabaseQueue.m:23
    4:65: warning: parameter of overriding method should be annotated with __attribute__((noescape))
    [-Wmissing-noescape]
    - (void)inTransaction:(void (^)(FMDatabase *db, BOOL *rollback))block {
                                                                    ^
    In file included from
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabaseQueue.m:9:
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabaseQueue.h:21
    1:91: note: parameter of overridden method is annotated with __attribute__((noescape))
    - (void)inTransaction:(__attribute__((noescape)) void (^)(FMDatabase *db, BOOL *rollback))block;
                                                                                              ^
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabaseQueue.m:23
    8:67: warning: parameter of overriding method should be annotated with __attribute__((noescape))
    [-Wmissing-noescape]
    - (NSError*)inSavePoint:(void (^)(FMDatabase *db, BOOL *rollback))block {
                                                                      ^
    In file included from
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabaseQueue.m:9:
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabaseQueue.h:23
    1:104: note: parameter of overridden method is annotated with __attribute__((noescape))
    - (NSError * _Nullable)inSavePoint:(__attribute__((noescape)) void (^)(FMDatabase *db, BOOL
    *rollback))block;
                                                                                                 ^
    4 warnings generated.
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabasePool.m:238
    :46: warning: parameter of overriding method should be annotated with __attribute__((noescape))
    [-Wmissing-noescape]
    - (void)inDatabase:(void (^)(FMDatabase *db))block {
                                                 ^
    In file included from
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabasePool.m:15:
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabasePool.h:199
    :72: note: parameter of overridden method is annotated with __attribute__((noescape))
    - (void)inDatabase:(__attribute__((noescape)) void (^)(FMDatabase *db))block;
                                                                           ^
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabasePool.m:273
    :73: warning: parameter of overriding method should be annotated with __attribute__((noescape))
    [-Wmissing-noescape]
    - (void)inDeferredTransaction:(void (^)(FMDatabase *db, BOOL *rollback))block {
                                                                            ^
    In file included from
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabasePool.m:15:
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabasePool.h:213
    :99: note: parameter of overridden method is annotated with __attribute__((noescape))
    - (void)inDeferredTransaction:(__attribute__((noescape)) void (^)(FMDatabase *db, BOOL
    *rollback))block;
                                                                                                 ^
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabasePool.m:277
    :65: warning: parameter of overriding method should be annotated with __attribute__((noescape))
    [-Wmissing-noescape]
    - (void)inTransaction:(void (^)(FMDatabase *db, BOOL *rollback))block {
                                                                    ^
    In file included from
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabasePool.m:15:
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabasePool.h:206
    :91: note: parameter of overridden method is annotated with __attribute__((noescape))
    - (void)inTransaction:(__attribute__((noescape)) void (^)(FMDatabase *db, BOOL *rollback))block;
                                                                                              ^
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabasePool.m:281
    :67: warning: parameter of overriding method should be annotated with __attribute__((noescape))
    [-Wmissing-noescape]
    - (NSError*)inSavePoint:(void (^)(FMDatabase *db, BOOL *rollback))block {
                                                                      ^
    In file included from
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabasePool.m:15:
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabasePool.h:224
    :104: note: parameter of overridden method is annotated with __attribute__((noescape))
    - (NSError * _Nullable)inSavePoint:(__attribute__((noescape)) void (^)(FMDatabase *db, BOOL
    *rollback))block;
                                                                                                 ^
    4 warnings generated.
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabase.m:1252:95
    : warning: parameter of overriding method should be annotated with __attribute__((noescape))
    [-Wmissing-noescape]
    - (BOOL)executeStatements:(NSString *)sql withResultBlock:(FMDBExecuteStatementsCallbackBlock)block {
                                                                                                 ^
    In file included from
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabase.m:1:
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabase.h:514:131
    : note: parameter of overridden method is annotated with __attribute__((noescape))
    - (BOOL)executeStatements:(NSString *)sql withResultBlock:(__attribute__((noescape))
    FMDBExecuteStatementsCallbackBlock _Nullable)block;
                                                                                                 ^
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabase.m:1394:51
    : warning: parameter of overriding method should be annotated with __attribute__((noescape))
    [-Wmissing-noescape]
    - (NSError*)inSavePoint:(void (^)(BOOL *rollback))block {
                                                      ^
    In file included from
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabase.m:1:
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabase.h:988:88:
    note: parameter of overridden method is annotated with __attribute__((noescape))
    - (NSError * _Nullable)inSavePoint:(__attribute__((noescape)) void (^)(BOOL *rollback))block;
                                                                                           ^
    2 warnings generated.
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExte
    rnalUserAgentIOSCustomBrowser.m:148:42: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:_appStoreURL];
                                             ^~~~~~~
                                             openURL:options:completionHandler:
    In module 'UIKit' imported from
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/AppAuth/AppAuth-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimu
    lator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:123:1: note: 'openURL:'
    has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:",
    ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
    ^
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExte
    rnalUserAgentIOSCustomBrowser.m:156:61: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      BOOL openedInBrowser = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:requestURL];
                                                                ^~~~~~~
                                                                openURL:options:completionHandler:
    In module 'UIKit' imported from
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/AppAuth/AppAuth-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimu
    lator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:123:1: note: 'openURL:'
    has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:",
    ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
    ^
    2 warnings generated.
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExte
    rnalUserAgentIOS.m:52:3: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      SFAuthenticationSession *_authenticationVC;
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      ASWebAuthenticationSession
    In module 'SafariServices' imported from
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExte
    rnalUserAgentIOS.m:25:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimu
    lator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/Headers/SFAuthenticationSession.h:48:1
    2: note: 'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
               ^
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExte
    rnalUserAgentIOS.m:131:7: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS
    12.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          SFAuthenticationSession *authenticationVC =
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          ASWebAuthenticationSession
    In module 'SafariServices' imported from
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExte
    rnalUserAgentIOS.m:25:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimu
    lator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/Headers/SFAuthenticationSession.h:48:1
    2: note: 'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
               ^
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExte
    rnalUserAgentIOS.m:132:37: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS
    12.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
              [[SFAuthenticationSession alloc] initWithURL:requestURL
                                        ^~~~~
                                        ASWebAuthenticationSession
    In module 'SafariServices' imported from
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExte
    rnalUserAgentIOS.m:25:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimu
    lator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/Headers/SFAuthenticationSession.h:48:1
    2: note: 'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
               ^
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExte
    rnalUserAgentIOS.m:168:58: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        openedUserAgent = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:requestURL];
                                                             ^~~~~~~
                                                             openURL:options:completionHandler:
    In module 'UIKit' imported from
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/AppAuth/AppAuth-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimu
    lator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:123:1: note: 'openURL:'
    has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:",
    ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
    ^
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExte
    rnalUserAgentIOS.m:191:3: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS
    12.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      SFAuthenticationSession *authenticationVC = _authenticationVC;
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      ASWebAuthenticationSession
    In module 'SafariServices' imported from
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExte
    rnalUserAgentIOS.m:25:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimu
    lator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/Headers/SFAuthenticationSession.h:48:1
    2: note: 'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
               ^
    5 warnings generated.
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/GTMAppAuth/Source/GTMAppAuthFetche
    rAuthorization+Keychain.m:31:26: warning: 'unarchiveObjectWithData:' is deprecated: first deprecated in
    iOS 12.0 - Use +unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error: instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:passwordData];
                             ^
    In module 'Foundation' imported from
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/GTMAppAuth/Source/GTMKeychain.h:19
    :
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimu
    lator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSKeyedArchiver.h:152:1: note:
    'unarchiveObjectWithData:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    + (nullable id)unarchiveObjectWithData:(NSData *)data API_DEPRECATED("Use
    +unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error: instead", macosx(10.2,10.14), ios(2.0,12.0), watchos(2.0,5.0),
    tvos(9.0,12.0));
    ^
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/GTMAppAuth/Source/GTMAppAuthFetche
    rAuthorization+Keychain.m:41:48: warning: 'archivedDataWithRootObject:' is deprecated: first deprecated
    in iOS 12.0 - Use +archivedDataWithRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:error: instead
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      NSData *authorizationData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:auth];
                                                   ^
    In module 'Foundation' imported from
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/projects/schwungfit/schwungfit/ios/Pods/GTMAppAuth/Source/GTMKeychain.h:19
    :
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimu
    lator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSKeyedArchiver.h:47:1: note:
    'archivedDataWithRootObject:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    + (NSData *)archivedDataWithRootObject:(id)rootObject API_DEPRECATED("Use
    +archivedDataWithRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:error: instead", macosx(10.2,10.14), ios(2.0,12.0),
    watchos(2.0,5.0), tvos(9.0,12.0));
    ^
    2 warnings generated.
    /* com.apple.ibtool.document.warnings */
    /Users/arditneziri/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-4.0.0+4/io
    s/Storyboards/WebView.storyboard:global: warning: This file is set to build for a version older than
    the deployment target. Functionality may be limited. [9]
    Plugin `sqflite` doesn't implement a plugin interface, nor sets a default implementation...
    Plugin `cloud_firestore` doesn't implement a plugin interface, nor sets a default implementation ...

    Plugin `firebase_auth` doesn't implement a plugin interface, nor sets a default implementation ...
    Plugin `firebase_core` doesn't implement a plugin interface, nor sets a default implementation ...
    Plugin `firebase_storage` doesn't implement a plugin interface, nor sets a default implementation ...
    Plugin `path_provider_linux` doesn't implement a plugin interface, nor sets a default implementation ...
    Plugin `path_provider_macos` doesn't implement a plugin interface, nor sets a default implementation ...
    Plugin `path_provider_windows` doesn't implement a plugin interface, nor sets a default implementation ...

    Plugin `shared_preferences_linux` doesn't implement a plugin interface, nor sets a default
    implementation ...
    Plugin `shared_preferences_macos` doesn't implement a plugin interface, nor sets a default
    implementation ...
    Plugin `shared_preferences_windows` doesn't implement a plugin interface, nor sets a default
    implementation ...
    ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1111:7: Error:
    Struct 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
    class ENUMLOGFONTEX extends Struct {
          ^
    ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2835:7: Error:
    Struct 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
    class BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO extends Struct {
          ^
    ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2960:7: Error:
    Struct 'EXCEPINFO' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
    class EXCEPINFO extends Struct {}
          ^
    ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2966:7: Error:
    Struct 'PROPERTYKEY' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
    class PROPERTYKEY extends Struct {}
          ^
    ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2973:7: Error:
    Struct 'PROPVARIANT' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
    class PROPVARIANT extends Struct {}
          ^
    ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2978:7: Error:
    Struct 'SAFEARRAY' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
    class SAFEARRAY extends Struct {}
          ^
    ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2985:7: Error:
    Struct 'CLSID' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
    class CLSID extends Struct {}
          ^
    ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2992:7: Error:
    Struct 'STATSTG' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
    class STATSTG extends Struct {}
          ^
    ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2999:7: Error:
    Struct 'NLM_SIMULATED_PROFILE_INFO' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
    class NLM_SIMULATED_PROFILE_INFO extends Struct {}
          ^
    ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart:23:7: Error: Struct
    'Utf8' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
    class Utf8 extends Struct {
          ^
    ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf16.dart:16:7: Error: Struct
    'Utf16' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
    class Utf16 extends Struct {
          ^
    ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:6:7:
    Error: Struct 'char' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
    class char extends Struct {}
          ^
    ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:8:7:
    Error: Struct 'sqlite3' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
    class sqlite3 extends Struct {}
          ^
    ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:10:7:
    Error: Struct 'sqlite3_stmt' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
    class sqlite3_stmt extends Struct {}
          ^
    ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:12:7:
    Error: Struct 'sqlite3_value' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
    class sqlite3_value extends Struct {}
          ^
    ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqlite3-0.1.8/lib/src/ffi/sqlite3.ffi.dart:14:7:
    Error: Struct 'sqlite3_context' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
    class sqlite3_context extends Struct {}
          ^
    ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/allocation.dart:47:33: Error:
    Expected type 'T' to be a valid and instantiated subtype of 'NativeType'.
      final int totalSize = count * sizeOf<T>();
                                    ^

    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue in Flutter's master channel with path provider.
You can solve it by switching to the stable channel.

You have to run in your terminal:

```
$ flutter channel stable
```